# N-Queen backtracking in C++ weird

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

So I have this code, and I'm trying to create my own n-queen program in c++ to learning the algorithm and backtracking.

But there's some weird behavior that I don't understand in the line 46, it's not setting back the 2D char array of specified index to '0', but if I move the code in line 46 to line 48, it worked. Any explanation why this is happen?

And second question, when I move the code in line 46 to line 48, it worked fine, the output of the array 2d correct. But the final return of function f isn't like what I expected, instead prints 4, it prints out 62.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool check(char g[][4],int x, int y){
    for (int i=x,j=y; i>-1 && y>-1; i--,j--)
        if (g[i][j]=='1')
            return false;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        if (g[i][y]=='1')
            return false;
    for (int i=x,j=y; i>-1 && j<4; i--, j++)
        if (g[i][j]=='1')
            return false;
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
        if (g[x][j]=='1')
            return false;
    for (int i=x,j=y; i<4 && j<4; i++, j++)
        if (g[i][j]=='1')
            return false;
    for (int i=x,j=y; i<4 && j>-1; i++, j--)
        if (g[i][j]=='1')
            return false;
    return true;
}
bool done(char g[][4]){
    int counts=0;
    for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            if (g[i][j]=='1')
                counts++;
        }
    }
    if (count==4)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
int f(char g[][4],int n, int m){
    if (done(g)){
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++){
                if (check(g,i,j)){
                    g[i][j]='1';
                    return 1 + f(g,n,m);
                    g[i][j]='0'; //Backtracking
                }

        }
    }

    return -1;
}
int main(){
    char gr[4][4]={
    {'0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0'},
    {'0','0','0','0'}
    };

    cout << f(gr,4,4) << endl << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            cout << gr[i][j] << " ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is line 46 ??

Comment: Please add comments in code to indicate line 46 and 48.

Comment: code is past a return ?

Answer (score 0):

You return 1 + f(g,n,m); in line 45 int the if scope. so the line 46 will never be reached.

if you place line 46 to 48 you get out of the scope where the return blocks its execution.

you should never place code between a return and the scope ending bracket.

ylso in many IDEs you would get a response that there is unreachable code.

thats pretty much all :)

[image]